# How distributed IDF (its architecture) is implemented in solr5?

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

I am wondering how solr5 has implemented distributed IDF. We have our own distributed search engine based on lucene and we want to take the advantages of distributed IDF. Searching google, I did not find any clue how solr5 implemented the following strategies:

```
LocalStatsCache: Local document stats.
ExactStatsCache: One time use aggregation
ExactSharedStatsCache: Stats shared across requests
LRUStatsCache: Stats shared in an LRU cache across requests
```

Are there any documentations describing their architectures? Or any suggestion for desiging such a thing?

Comment: I have already checked Solr Documentation, but it is only a brief out of box section about configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLR-1632](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1632) is the JIRA issue that tracked the implementation of the Distributed Stats-support (which is part of the distributed idf support) in Solr5. It includes the patches as well, so you should be able to see any details about how the actual implementation was done.

There is still a lot of documentation talking about tf/idf scores per shard, although that may just be outdated documentation at this point.